# Как удалять записи из базы данных, старше 1го месяца?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, cron

Есть база данных, содержащая записи, которые имеют дату, и со временем таких записей становится больше. Как можно удалять записи, старше одного месяца?
Т.е чтобы в базе хранились данные месяц (допустим 30 дней), а затем, если наступал 31 день, они удалялись автоматически

Слышал про cron-задачи, но нигде не смог найти внятной информации и понятных примеров.

Об этом знаю буквально день, поэтому заранее прошу меня простить

Может кто подсказать, как это делается, пожалуйста?

Всё написано на php-фреймворке symfony

Comment: [Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: Можете посмотреть в сторону партиционирования. Можете посмотреть в сторону простого удаления по крону. 

Сделайте консольную команду, которую будете запускать по крону , где будет выполняться ваш sql запрос, дропающий ваши данные по выбранному вами условию . В конце концов можете сделать триггер. Вот что то типа этого https://stackoverflow.com/a/26063344/3725361